# This pine script code don't understand to formula and meanning

Tags: pine-script

Now convert to pinescript to python.
But don't understand this code's meaning and formula. line 15

pdmS = ((1 - k)*nz(pdmS[1]) + k*pdm)

```
study(title="Variable Moving Average [LazyBear]", shorttitle="VMA_LB", overlay=true)
src=close
l =input(6, title="VMA Length") 
std=input(true, title="Show Trend Direction")
bc=input(false, title="Color bars based on Trend")
k = 1.0/l
pdm = max((src - src[1]), 0)
mdm = max((src[1] - src), 0)
pdmS = ((1 - k)*nz(pdmS[1]) + k*pdm)
mdmS = ((1 - k)*nz(mdmS[1]) + k*mdm)
s = pdmS + mdmS
pdi = pdmS/s
mdi = mdmS/s
pdiS = ((1 - k)*nz(pdiS[1]) + k*pdi)
mdiS = ((1 - k)*nz(mdiS[1]) + k*mdi)
d = abs(pdiS - mdiS)
s1 = pdiS + mdiS
iS = ((1 - k)*nz(iS[1]) + k*d/s1)
hhv = highest(iS, l) 
llv = lowest(iS, l) 
d1 = hhv - llv
vI = (iS - llv)/d1
vma = (1 - k*vI)*nz(vma[1]) + k*vI*src
vmaC=(vma > vma[1]) ? green : (vma<vma[1]) ? red : (vma==vma[1]) ? blue : black 
plot(vma, color=std?vmaC:black, linewidth=3, title="VMA")
barcolor(bc?vmaC:na)
```

Comment: What is that you don't understand? Is it the formula? Is it the `nz()` function? Is it the `[]` operator? Please be more specific.

Comment: thanks for your comment. now solute that problem. just pdiS = ((1 - k)*nz(pdiS[1]) + k*pdi) formula => pinescript's RMA func

Comment: @김주민 so it works as you expect? You've solve your issue?

Comment: yes now not problem complete